# How to add extra field in hbase through nutch?

Tags: hbase, nutch

I am writing a nutch plugin at fetch time. I am doing some analysis on the fetched webpages and the results are to be stored in hbase corresponding to the webpage. I am not sure how to add an extra field and how to write data to that field using nutch.

Comment: try to update schema.xml !!

Comment: are you want to add additional field while indexing ?

Comment: were you able to add extra field in hbase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If You want to add Additional Fields While indexing in Solr ::***

If the value of the additional fields fixed (Static), then you can use the Nutch's index-static plugin.

It allows you to add a number of fields with their contents.

**Step 1:**

You first need to enable index.static property in nutch-site.xml

**Step 2:**

Add index.static property

```
<property>
 <name>index.static</name>
 <value>first_field:value,second_field:value</value>
 <description>
  Used by plugin index-static to adds fields with static data at indexing time. 
   You can specify a comma-separated list of fieldname:fieldcontent per Nutch job.
  Each fieldcontent can have multiple values separated by space, e.g.,
   field1:value1.1 value1.2 value1.3,field2:value2.1 value2.2 ...
   It can be useful when collections can't be created by URL patterns, 
  like in subcollection, but on a job-basis.
  </description>
</property>
```

**Step 3:**

Add field definition in schema.xml

**Step 4:**

Enabled the index in plugin.includes

**Or** You can follow https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample-1.2 for Writing Plugin